# I am trying to get the average of the numbers in an array in javascript but it's not working how I want to

Tags: javascript, html

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="return false">
      <label for="sub">Subjects</label>
      <input type="number" id="eh" /><br /><br />
      <label for="sub1">Subject 1 marks:</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="num" id="num1" /><br />
      <label for="sub2">Subject 2 marks:</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="num" id="num2" /><br />
      <label for="sub3">Subject 3 marks:</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="num" id="num3" /><br />
      <label for="sub4">Subject 4 marks:</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="num" id="num4" /><br />
      <label for="sub5">Subject 5 marks:</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="num" id="num5" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="he()" />
    </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
function he() {
    var subcount = document.getElementById("eh").value;
    var marks1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var marks2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var marks3 = document.getElementById("num3").value;
    var marks4 = document.getElementById("num4").value;
    var marks5 = document.getElementById("num5").value;

    var marks =  []

    marks.push(marks1)
    marks.push(marks2)
    marks.push(marks3)
    marks.push(marks4)
    marks.push(marks5)

    const sum = marks.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);

    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = sum / subcount

    // console.log(marks)

}
```

[The answer is supposed to be 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMKxW.jpg)

I want the result to be the 500 / 5
But it isn't working. Pls, help me fix this and explain the problem.
I don't think there's something wrong with my code or if there is pls tell me what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//  Please use the Number() function

```
const sum = marks.reduce((partialSum, a) => Number(partialSum) + Number(a),0)
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = sum / Number(subcount)
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other questions
And I have tested it before posted

Comment: This is the kind of little mistake that would have easily been caught using TypeScript and could have prevented even needing to write this SO question!

Comment: So! I have another question. please solve this if you can. SO imagine there's a program if you enter a value in the subject count input field. The number of input fields should be generated according to the subject count's value. So for example if I enter 5 in the subject count field. 5 input fields should generate. And how do I get the average? 

Pls, solve this thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topcoder007/pen/QWmLKOP?editors=1111

Please let me after check it

Answer (score 2):

You can get the average like this:

```js
const marks = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
const average = marks.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / marks.length
console.log(`Average: ${average}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.getElementById("num1").value` got a string, not a number, In JavaScript, the + operator is used for both numeric addition and string concatenation. When you "add" a number to a string the interpreter converts your number to a string and concatenates both together. you should handle `marks` like this:

```js
...
marks = marks.map(i => Number(i))

const sum = marks.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
```

You can get the example in jsbin, https://jsbin.com/gavutah/edit?html,js,console,output